# receiving one result in 1st field through ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i have 3 text field with jquery calender plugin working...
the  issue I am facing is that in the very first field of input the date pass the ajax function and returns the value from data base via php but the second and the third fields doesn't passes their values to ajax so I am not receiving the value.

the Ajax code is given below

```
$('.submit-button').on('click',function(){
    var name = $('input#popupDatepicker').val();
    var id = $(this).attr('id').split('_')[1];
    if ($.trim(name,id)!=''){
        $.post('pages/name.php',{name:name,id:id},function(data){
            $('div#name-data').html(data);
            document.getElementById("#name-data").innerHTML =(data);
        });
    }
});
```

---

The Html code

```
> input type="text" class="datecontrol" id="popupDatepicker"
```

this is the input field and it is replicated in while loop as im getting data from database

Comment: Why do you mix `$()` query selector and `document.getElementById()`? When using `document.getElementById()` dont specify `#` in ID name

Comment: I have a feeling you're using the same id for all three of your date inputs. But as @MihaiIorga said please show us your HTML.

Comment: So long as #name-data is a div, you do realize that $('div#name-data').html(data); and document.getElementById("#name-data").innerHTML =(data); both do the exact same thing right?

Comment: ive shared my html and @kitsched u r right im using same id but as it is iterating in loop so it generates with every record in it !!

Comment: Even if your HTML is generated you should never have the same id twice in your HTML page.

Comment: @kitsched  my whole file is provided here 
http://pastie.org/4746295